# Which have most chances to be killed First: Android Services, Activity, AsyncTask, HandlerThread?

Tags: android, performance

Say, I've declared

1. few activities (here, talking about some activity which is last in the stack)
2. an Asynctask in the 1st case inside activity, the 2nd case outside class,
3. and also have Android Services,
4. HandlerThreads also.
   To do some extra works on Worker / other threads via all these cases(except 1. )

My question is If Android have to kill these, which will be killed first, then which one to the last, in order to fulfill the need of resources at some time?

Thanks, any Real guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how Android kills things.  Threads can't be killed (this includes HandlerThreads and AsyncTasks).  There is no safe way to do so without introducing the possibility of deadlock or data corruption.  Services and Activities can be stopped, but that doesn't stop any thread they started from running-  only killing the process can do that.  However a killed Service/Activity would no longer be a valid context and would not be able to perform some actions.

Comment: Okay, @gabesechan, I know Threads can't be killed directly and I agree that only process can do that (Services and Activities can be stopped), But say, now you have these just 4 cases all in different processes, then which'll get chance to be killed first and last..?